# MS SQL - How do I query something from one table to properly insert data into other table

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

The Facts:
I have 2 Tables in my MS SQL Database:
Table1 has two columns: GUID, StockSymbol

Table2 has 2 columns: GUID, StockCompanyName

I have a populated list (excel) of StockSymbol & CompanyName

I have "most" of the stock symbols already in Table1 with their GUID.
I have "most" of the GUID's already in Table2 (some have a Blank CompanyName, some have a placemarker name temporarily)

What I need help on:
I want to populate Table2 with the CompanyName from appropriate GUID on Table1 from my populated list

My basic idea of what needs to happen (may be wrong):
My idea was to first run something that checked if the symbol existed in table 1, if not then make the guid, and insert the symbol. 
Then insert CompanyName in Table2, while query Table1 to insert into the Table2 to properly match up the symbol & guid and populate the CompanyName field.

Any help will be appreciated.  Right now, i have been running two queries from the two tables and eyeball them in small chunks and copy pasting into the editor -driving me nuts knowing there is a better way!

Comment: What is the source data that you are inserting into table 1? If you had that also in a table you could write a query to insert to the other 2 tables rather easily.

Comment: Checkout the SQL command merge: you can specify different behavior depending on the existence/non-existence of the GUID (you'll need a SQL function to create the GUID for this to help you, though: if GUID creation takes place outside of SQL merge won't help you)

Comment: We need some more information. You mention that table 1 has the stock symbol, while table 2 has the company name. You then mention you have an Excel that contains the company name and the stock symbol. That information would need to be in a table before you could do what you're asking with a query.